# Coverage report of multi module project

Tags: junit, code-coverage, cobertura, jacoco, sonar-runner

I am having a issue with generating code coverage report and getting an analysis of unit tests covering the project code. I have used Sonar to get a report on project but the unit test coverage section do not show anything. I have done some research and found that sonar needs to have a junit report generated by emma/clover/corbetura/jacoco. The project is non-maven based. Please tell me how can I analyse code coverage for a non-maven based multi-module project. I am using sonar runner.

Any link or reference will be helpful.
Please do not give links of documentation pages. Apparently, I have browsed them all.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm giving the links to the documentation pages to help others who have not seen the documentation or examples.  Take the maven property settings and translate them into sonar-runner.properties.  For example, depending on how you set up your multi-module project you might put this setting in the parent level or inside each module: `sonar.jacoco.reportPath=reports/coverage/jacoco.exec`

Here is the link to the multi-module sonar runner project:

http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Runner

To configure unit test code coverage apply the same properties in maven to the sonar-project.properties file.  Here is the example from the Code Coverage example:

https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/projects/code-coverage

Note you need to set the unit and coverage properties as well as the source encoding properties.

```
 
    sonar.projectKey=org.codehaus.sonar:example-ut-sonarRunner-jacoco-reuseReports
    sonar.projectName=UT coverage with SonarQube Runner reusing JUnit and JaCoCo reports
    sonar.projectVersion=1.0

    sonar.sources=src
    sonar.binaries=classes
    sonar.language=java

    # Tells SonarQube to reuse existing reports for unit tests execution and coverage reports
    sonar.dynamicAnalysis=reuseReports

    # Tells SonarQube where the unit tests execution reports are
    sonar.junit.reportsPath=reports/junit

    # Tells SonarQube that the code coverage tool by unit tests is JaCoCo
    sonar.java.coveragePlugin=jacoco

    # Tells SonarQube where the unit tests code coverage report is
    sonar.jacoco.reportPath=reports/coverage/jacoco.exec

    # Encoding of the source files
    sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
```

Comment: For multi-module project you I have the following setup:
`sonar.sources=src1,src2,src3
sonar.binaries=classes1,classes2,classes3
sonar.binaries=classes1,classes2,classes3`
For me it shows only tests result and coverage for src1.
Specifying `sonar.dynamicAnalysis=reuseReports` didn't help.